# div hover is not staying steady ,want to create navigation hover like paytm website

Tags: html, css

The hover `div` of items should stay stable but it doesn't, when I move cursor from hover a tag it goes away

```css
#ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: orange;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

li.dropdown2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul1">
  <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="services"> Services </a> </li>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="dropbtn"> Products </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul id="ul2">
        <li class="dropdown2"> <a href="#"> Mobiles </a>
          <div class="dropdown-content2">
            <a href="#"> Mobile1 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile2 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile3 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile4 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile5 </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Televisions </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Microwave </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Clothing </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Footware </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried many things to deal with this like scaling padding to max or increasing width and height but nothing works.
The `div` goes away as soon as I move my cursor for hovered item

Comment: Please post your html code so others can help you.

Comment: i have added above

Comment: i have add my code in one format

Comment: Could you please describe the behavior in more detail? When you hover on a menu its submenus are displayed. When you hover out, the submenus are hidden. This is standard behavior for drop-down menus, unless you define a different event that makes the menu disappear, like clicking on the parent menu item. What event would make the menu disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `position:absolute` from the dropdown `<a>` tags and fixed the positioning of each dropdown level. This resolves the positioning of submenus in relation to the parent menu.

The hover mechanism works well with the arrangement of the menus. When you hover out, the menus disappear, which is standard behavior for drop-down menus. If you wish to leave the menu visible on hover out, you will need to define a javascript function that controls menu visibility, for instance, hiding when clicking on a menu item.

```css
#ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  width: 160px;
}

li {
  width: 160px;
  display: block;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: orange;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

li.dropdown2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left:166px;
  margin-top:-46px;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left:160px;
  margin-top:-46px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  /*padding: 20px 20px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  /*padding: 20px 20px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
}

#ul2 {padding:0px;}
```

```html
<ul id="ul1">
  <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="services"> Services </a> </li>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Products</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul id="ul2">
        <li class="dropdown2" style="position:relative;"> <a href="#"> Mobiles </a>
          <div class="dropdown-content2">
            <a href="#"> Mobile1 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile2 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile3 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile4 </a>
            <a href="#"> Mobile5 </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Televisions </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Microwave </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Clothing </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Footware </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```